# Calculate average price of stock from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame save order history when trading stock. The example data will be shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

date = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
price = [1020, 1050, 1110, 1080, 1050, 1020, 1050, 1110, 1080, 1050, 1050, 1140, 1110, 1100, 1140, 1170, 1200]
vol = [100, 0, 200, 0, -300, 100, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, -100, -100, 100, 0, 0, -200]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'price': price, 'vol': vol})
```

I want to calculate the average price of the trades I have made.

I have tried many methods and still can't seem to get it right.

This is my approach:

```
sum_stock = np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: 0 if a + b < 0 else a + b, 2, 1)
df['num_of_stocks'] = sum_stock.accumulate(df.vol.values)
df['bought_price'] = df.loc[df['num_of_stocks'] > 0, 'price']
df['bought_vol'] = df.loc[df['num_of_stocks'] > 0, 'vol'].apply(lambda x: max(x, 0))
df['bought_value'] = df['bought_price'] * df['bought_vol']
sum_value = np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: a + b if b == b else 0, 2, 1)
df['cumulative_bought_value'] = sum_value.accumulate(df['bought_value'].values)
df['cumulative_bought_vol'] = sum_value.accumulate(df['bought_vol'].values)
df['avg_price'] = df.loc[df['cumulative_bought_value'] > 0, 'cumulative_bought_value'] / df.loc[df['cumulative_bought_vol'] > 0, 'cumulative_bought_vol']
df = df.fillna(0)
```

And this is output:

```
avg_price = [1020.0, 1020.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 0.0, 1020.0, 1020.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1085.0, 1085.0, 1085.0, 0.0]
```

Look the output, I can see that if I buy, hold, and sell all. My code will correct.

However, if I buy, hold, sell a portion, and then buy again, it will result in an error in the calculation of the average price.

This is my desired output:

```
avg_price = [1020, 1020, 1080, 1080, 0, 1020, 1020, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1090, 1090, 1090, 0]
```

I will explain:

On the first day, I bought 100 shares at a price of 1020, so the average price is 1020.

On the second day, I did not buy or sell, so the average price remained unchanged.

On the third day, I bought 200 shares at a price of 1110, so the average price became $(100 * 1020 + 200 * 1110) / (100 + 200) = 1080$.

On the fourth day, I did not buy or sell, so the average price remained unchanged.

On the fifth day, I sold all of my shares, so the average price became zero.

Similarly, from the sixth to the thirteenth day, I obtained the average price as indicated in the output.

However, on the fourteenth day, I bought 300 shares and sold 200 shares before. At this point, I had 100 shares remaining, and the average price was 1080. Then, I bought an additional 100 shares at a price of 1100. The new average price would be $(100 * 1080 + 100 * 1100) / (100 + 100) = 1090$.

My code is incorrect because I have used the total bought value until the number of shares becomes zero. Can you please help me find the desired output without using a for loop? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way of doing this without looping, because calculating the average price of your current stocks is dependent on both the information of the current row, and the outcome of the same calculation of the previous row. Due to this iterative nature of the problem, I solved it like this:

```
# create a column with cumulative volume, which represents your stock level on any given day.
df['cumvol'] = df['vol'].cumsum()

# Set the first average price (we need an inception)
df.loc[0,'avg'] = df.loc[0,'price']

# loop over the remaining rows.
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'vol'] == 0:
        # take previous row value
        df.loc[i, 'avg'] = df.loc[i-1, 'avg']
    elif df.loc[i, 'vol'] > 0:
        # calculate new average
        df.loc[i, 'avg'] = ((df.loc[i-1, 'cumvol']*df.loc[i-1, 'avg']) + (df.loc[i, 'vol']*df.loc[i, 'price'])) / (df.loc[i, 'cumvol'])
    elif (df.loc[i, 'vol'] < 0) & (df.loc[i, 'cumvol'] > 0):
        # take previous row value
        df.loc[i, 'avg'] = df.loc[i-1, 'avg']
    else:
        # vol < 0 and cumsum = 0
        df.loc[i, 'avg'] = 0
print(df)

    date  price  vol  cumvol     avg
0      1   1020  100     100  1020.0
1      2   1050    0     100  1020.0
2      3   1110  200     300  1080.0
3      4   1080    0     300  1080.0
4      5   1050 -300       0     0.0
5      6   1020  100     100  1020.0
6      7   1050    0     100  1020.0
7      8   1110  200     300  1080.0
8      9   1080    0     300  1080.0
9     10   1050    0     300  1080.0
10    11   1050    0     300  1080.0
11    12   1140 -100     200  1080.0
12    13   1110 -100     100  1080.0
13    14   1100  100     200  1090.0
14    15   1140    0     200  1090.0
15    16   1170    0     200  1090.0
16    17   1200 -200       0     0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! In reality, I have a large dataset, so using a for loop wastes a lot of time.

Comment: Yeah I figured. Unfortunately, for each row where you make a buy, you can only calculate the new avg price by knowing the previous (calculated) avg price. Vectorizing is therefor not possible and you have to calculate them in order of their occurrence, hence the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with quite same task to solve for perpetual futures, so here is my solution:

The 'Entry Price' is calculated by considering the price of each order that contributed to the opening of the position and the corresponding quantity of contracts.

Entry price of multiple orders = average price of multiple orders
Entry Price = (Σ (Order Price x Order Quantity)) / Total Quantity

when we calculate for a long position, sales do not affect on 'Entry Price' but we
reduce basis cost on sales.

step by step:

```
date 6: basis cost (1020*100); 
avg = basis cost / total vol = 1020
date 8: basis cost (1020*100)+(1110*200); 
avg = basis cost(324 000) / total vol(300) = 1080
date 12: basis cost (1020*100)+(1110*200)+( -100 * (current 'avg' which is(1080)) ); 
basis cost(216 000) 
total vol(200) 
avg = will remain same, 1080
date 13: basis cost (1020*100)+(1110*200)+(-100*1080)+( -100 * (current 'avg' which is still (1080)) ); 
basis cost(108 000) 
total vol(100) 
avg = will remain same, 1080
date 14: basis cost (1020*100)+(1110*200)+(-100*1080)+(-100*1080)+(1100*100) ); 
avg = basis cost(218 000) / total vol(200) = 1090
```

Solution #1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        'price': [1020, 1050, 1110, 1080, 1050, 1020, 1050, 1110, 1080, 1050, 1050, 1140, 1110, 1100, 1140, 1170, 1200],
        'shares': [100, 0, 200, 0, -300, 100, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, -100, -100, 100, 0, 0, -200]#,
        #'expected_results': [1020.0, 1020.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 0.0, 1020.0, 1020.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1080.0, 1090.0, 1090.0, 1090.0, 0.0]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Cumulative number of shares
df['cum_shares'] = df['shares'].cumsum()

# Column with the expected result for comparison
df['avg_price_weight'] = np.nan

# Loop for calculating the weighted average price line by line
for i in range(len(df)):
  # Reset the average price in case of a full sale
  if df['cum_shares'][i]==0:
    df['avg_price_weight'][i]=0
  
  # For the first row, the average price is the purchase price
  elif i==0:
    df['avg_price_weight'][i]=df['price'][i]
  
  # When selling, keep the previous average price
  elif df['shares'][i]<0:
    df['avg_price_weight'][i]=df['avg_price_weight'][i-1]

  # Calculate the average price as the average of the previous recorded spending and current
  else:
    df['avg_price_weight'][i]=(df['avg_price_weight'][i-1] * df['cum_shares'][i-1] + df['price'][i] * df['shares'][i])/df['cum_shares'][i] 

print(df)
```

Solution #2, which is made because i wished to reach most 'pandas' solution as i can

```
import pandas as pd

date = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
price = [1020, 1050, 1110, 1080, 1050, 1020, 1050, 1110, 1080, 1050, 1050, 1140, 1110, 1100, 1140, 1170, 1200]
shares = [100, 0, 200, 0, -300, 100, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, -100, -100, 100, 0, 0, -200]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'price': price, 'shares': shares})

pd.set_option("display.precision", 3)
df['shares_cost'] = df.price * df.shares # represent value of bought / sold shares at moment
df['position_shares'] =  df['shares'].cumsum() # holding position volume 
groups = df.where(df.position_shares !=0).groupby((df['position_shares'] == 0).cumsum()) #group by rows where we IN postion

def entry_price(group:pd.DataFrame):
    last_entry_price, my_cum_sum = 0,0
    
    def row_handler(row):
        nonlocal last_entry_price, my_cum_sum
        #print(pd.DataFrame(row).T) #Debug
        if (row.shares > 0):
            my_cum_sum += (row.shares_cost) 
            last_entry_price = my_cum_sum / row.position_shares
        elif (row.shares < 0):
            my_cum_sum += (row.shares*last_entry_price) 
        return last_entry_price
    
    group['_'] = group.apply(row_handler , axis=1)
    #print(group) #debug
    
    return group['_']


df['entry_price'] = groups.apply(entry_price).droplevel(0)

print('-'*10)
print(df)
```

As question author (Nhân Phan Thành) told “I have a large dataset, so using a for loop wastes a lot of time. ” i decided to check performance question of JarroVGIT solution and both mine, measured cacled as average of 100 calls by given example below:

```
start = time.time()
#call solution
end = time.time()
result =  (end-start)
```

The result will still remain very subjective due to the differences in the hardware part on which the code is run.
After all, got following result

1. mine Solution #1 37% slower then mine Solution #2
2. JarroVGIT solution and mine Solution #2 almost equal